# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource: - Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I would like to try PEGASUS to summarize article. 
https://github.com/google-research/pegasus

I followed this instruction.
https://github.com/google-research/pegasus/tree/f76b63c2886748f7f5c6c9fb547456d8c6002562#setup

I checked the region which I can use `NVIDIA Tesla V100` and I decided to use `us-central1-a`
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus

I used this command.

```
gcloud compute instances create pegasustest --zone=us-central1-a 
--machine-type=n1-highmem-8 --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1 
--boot-disk-size=500GB --image-project=ml-images --image-family=tf-1-15 
--maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure
```

I got this error message.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The zone 'projects/covid19agent/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough 
resources available to fulfill the request.  
Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

I took 3 hours and tried again, but I got the same result.

So, I changed the region from `us-central1-a` to `asia-east1-c`.

I used this command.

```
gcloud compute instances create pegasustest --zone=asia-east1-c 
--machine-type=n1-highmem-8 --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1 
--boot-disk-size=500GB --image-project=ml-images --image-family=tf-1-15 
--maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure
```

Then I got this error message.

```
WARNING: Some requests generated warnings:
 - Disk size: '500 GB' is larger than image size: '10 GB'. 
You might need to resize the root repartition manually 
if the operating system does not support automatic resizing. 
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd 
for details.

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded.  Limit: 0.0 globally.
```

Is it impossible for me to try PEGASUS? And, does it cost too much to try PEGASUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let's start with the first issue**. Have a look again at the error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - The zone 'projects/covid19agent/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough  resources available to fulfill the request.   Try a different
>   zone, or try again later.

When you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) it requests resources like vCPU, memory, GPU and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get such message, more information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

> If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
>   or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
>   resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
>   request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
>   and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

*There are a few ways to solve this issue*:

1. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again (as you tried, but fruitless this time).
2. Move your instance to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) (as you did).
3. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future:

   > Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
   >   zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
   >   additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
   >   your workloads when you need them. After you create a reservation, you
   >   begin paying for the reserved resources immediately, and they remain
   >   available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
   >   is deleted.

**Now, let's have a look at the second issue**. Have a look again at this error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
>    - Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded.  Limit: 0.0 globally.

More information about quotas you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

*To solve this issue you should follow steps below*:

1. Ensure that billing is enabled for your project.
2. [Request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota):

   > 1. Go to the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.215651731.561997706.1592211090-1698584973.1584367323&_gac=1.240772663.1589283527.EAIaIQobChMIoYamtZ6u6QIVwg8YCh1wBgcKEAAYASAAEgJE4PD_BwE) page.
   > 2. In the Quotas page, select the quotas you want to change.
   > 3. Click the Edit Quotas button on the top of the page.
   > 4. Check the box of the service you want to edit.
   > 5. Fill out your name, email, and phone number, and click Next.
   > 6. Enter your request to increase your quota, and click Next.
   > 7. Submit your request.
   > 8. A request to decrease quota is rejected by default. If you must reduce your quota, reply to the support email with an explanation of
   >      your requirements. A support representative from the Compute Engine
   >      team will respond to your request within 24 to 48 hours.

   You're not able to request an increase in quota if you use 12-month, $300 free trial because of the limitations:

   > Your free trial credit applies to all Google Cloud resources, with the
   >   following exceptions:
   >
   > - You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time.
   > - You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.
   > - You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see [Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).
   > - You can't create VM instances that are based on Windows Server [images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images).
   >
   > You must [upgrade your account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) to perform any of the actions in
   >   the preceding list.

**You can estimate cost of usage** with [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I totally understand. Unfortunately, pricing calculator was too complicated for me.

Comment: Thank you! You can try to contact [Google Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact) instead of using Google Cloud Pricing Calculator.

Comment: Thank you for an alternative choice. I will contact Google Cloud Sales.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved This Error simply by changing Zone.
Initially, it was `us-central-c`, and i changed it `us-central-b`.